# React: Edit and replace user input (onChange)

Tags: reactjs, user-input, onchange

Wassup Guys,

I am currently writing a react app. I have an input label, where an user can enter something. In my case, I just need digits and dashes (-). However, the input should be handled directly (means that I run my method the whole time in the background with the user's input after every digit). How can I work with this input, in order to write rules, that correct the number / digit input? 
 For instance, if someone writes "**--/--/---**" it should be displayed a blank string " ". I need this, in oder to write a datetime sanitizer for my user's input.

Below is my code. Thanks in advance!

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export const dateFormatter = (input) => {
  return input;
};

export default function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState("");

  const handleInput = (date) => {
    const inputValue = date.target.value;
    // setState(dateFormatter(inputValue));
    console.log("Not allowed! Only tests");
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input onChange={handleInput} defaultValue={state} maxLength="10" />
    </div>
  );
}
```

test.js (behaviour)

````
it("should handle initial input / reset input", () => {
    //Initial
    expect(dateFormatter("")).toBe("");

    // Removal
    expect(dateFormatter("--/--/---")).toBe("");
    expect(dateFormatter("-/--/----")).toBe("");
    expect(dateFormatter("--/-/----")).toBe("");
    expect(dateFormatter("--/------")).toBe("");
    expect(dateFormatter("----/----")).toBe("");
  });

  // Non-Ambiguous
  it("should shift digit left to right", () => {
    //Initial
    expect(dateFormatter("")).toBe("");

    it("should handle initial digit", () => {
      // Right to left block (1 Variant)
      expect(dateFormatter("0")).toBe("0-/--/----");
      expect(dateFormatter("1")).toBe("1-/--/----");
      expect(dateFormatter("2")).toBe("2-/--/----");
      expect(dateFormatter("3")).toBe("3-/--/----");
      expect(dateFormatter("4")).toBe("4-/--/----");
      expect(dateFormatter("5")).toBe("5-/--/----");
      expect(dateFormatter("6")).toBe("6-/--/----");
      expect(dateFormatter("7")).toBe("7-/--/----");
      expect(dateFormatter("8")).toBe("8-/--/----");
      expect(dateFormatter("9")).toBe("9-/--/----");
    });

    // Right to left block (1 Variant)
    it("should handle block shifting", () => {
      expect(dateFormatter("9-/--/----8")).toBe("98/--/----");
      expect(dateFormatter("98/--/----7")).toBe("98/7-/----");
      expect(dateFormatter("98/7-/----6")).toBe("98/76/----");
      expect(dateFormatter("98/76/----5")).toBe("98/76/5---");
      expect(dateFormatter("98/76/5---0")).toBe("98/76/5---");
      expect(dateFormatter("98/76/50--4")).toBe("98/76/504-");
    });

    it("should handle delimiter", () => {
      expect(dateFormatter("9-/--/----/")).toBe("09/--/----");
      expect(dateFormatter("09/--/----0")).toBe("09/0-/----");
      expect(dateFormatter("09/--/----/")).toBe("09/--/----");
      expect(dateFormatter("09/0-/----/")).toBe("09/00/----"); // geht nicht
      expect(dateFormatter("09/--/----/")).toBe("09/00/----");
    });

    it("should handle limits & delete", () => {
      expect(dateFormatter("09/00/0000/")).toBe("09/00/0000");
      expect(dateFormatter("09/00/000")).toBe("09/00/----");
      expect(dateFormatter("09/00/---")).toBe("09/--/----");
      expect(dateFormatter("09/0/----")).toBe("09/--/----");
      expect(dateFormatter("0/00/----")).toBe("--/--/----");
      expect(dateFormatter("09/-/----")).toBe("--/--/----");
    });

    it("should handle adding anywhere", () => {
      // add anywhere
      expect(dateFormatter("-9-/--/----")).toBe("9-/--/----");
      expect(dateFormatter("--/-9-/----")).toBe("9-/--/----");
      expect(dateFormatter("--/--/--9--")).toBe("9-/--/----");
      expect(dateFormatter("10/--/--9--")).toBe("10/9-/----");
      expect(dateFormatter("09/00/00001")).toBe("09/00/00001");
      expect(dateFormatter("09/00/000")).toBe("09/00/----");
      expect(dateFormatter("09/001/00000")).toBe("09/01/0000");
    });

    it("should handle deleting anywhere", () => {
      // delete anywhere
      expect(dateFormatter("0/00/----")).toBe("--/--/----");
      expect(dateFormatter("09/00/000")).toBe("09/00/----");
      expect(dateFormatter("09/00/----0")).toBe("09/00/0---");
      expect(dateFormatter("09/00/0---1")).toBe("09/00/01--");
      expect(dateFormatter("09/00/0---1")).toBe("09/00/01--");
    });

    it("should no year limits", () => {
      // ambigous - year on the left side?!
      // allow only when right side is years - only then!
      expect(dateFormatter("09/00/00001")).toBe("09/00/00001");
      expect(dateFormatter("09/00/000012")).toBe("09/00/000012");
    });

    ```
````

Answer (score 1):

I think you are talking about using some kind of a Mask for the user input, right?

You can make a function that uses a Regexp in order to validate the format of your choice.

This function should execute on keyup event, which is right when the user touches an input on the keyboard.

Something like this:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export const dateFormatter = (input) => {
  return input;
};

export default function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState("");

  const [maskedState, setMaskedState] = useState("");

  const dateMask = () => {
    setMaskedState(maskedState.replace(/\D/g, "")
      .replace(/(\d{2})(\d)/, " $1 / $2")
      .replace(/(\d{2})(\d)/, "$1 / $2")
      .replace(/(\ \d{4})\d+?$/, "$1"));
  }

  const rawDate = (date) => {
   setState(date.split(" / ").reverse().join("-").replace(" ", ""));
  }

  const handleInput = (date) => {
    const inputValue = date.target.value;
    dateMask(inputValue);
    rawDate(inputValue);
    console.log("Not allowed! Only tests");
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input onKeyUp={handleInput} defaultValue={maskedState} maxLength="10" />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: react tells me "Unnecessary escape character: \ . (no-useless-escape)eslint
" at line 17, does ```replace(/(\ \d{4})\d+?$/, "$1"));``` has a "\" too much?

Comment: but yeah the idea is correct, I want to "fix" the user's input and show it directly into the label everything the user enters or deletes anything (regarding if us / german layout) ```12152003 => "12/15/2003"```

Comment: It looks like the issue is with your es-lint config rather than the code itself, you might want to take a look at that.

The code should take an user Input, make sure to replace anything that is not a digit and the mask would look like "DD / MM / YYYY" with the raw input being "YYYY-DD-MM"

From there you can adjust to what you need, let me know if I can help with that

Comment: okay alright, I'll try to implement it now - but what I'm wondering is, what's our purpose of rawDate ? We don't use this in our component. Thank you, I'll give you an update when I encounter some issues

Comment: well, for my app, the user inputs a date, like "01/01/2020" and I use "2020-01-01" as a "formatted" value (the one I actually need), which is the purpose of the rawDate in the code.

Comment: Okay, well. But everytime I enter something like "01/01/2020" it is not fixed or somehow replaced - did you use something more than just this in your app?

Comment: check my edited post please, I need this kinda behaviour

Comment: I made a reproduction of your app and fixed the code:

[Check this rep](https://repl.it/join/qnkylkar-helrabelo1)